# Track multiple domains under the same google analytics account

Tags: google-analytics, multiple-domains

I have two domains mysite.com and mysite.cz and I want to see traffic sources for both domains, which i currently can't as i am tracking only ".com" domain. Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: These aren't sub domains they are separate domains.  The fact they share the same name is irrelevant if the top level domain (the .com/.cz) is different, so you should edit the question.

Comment: GA provides a Cross-Domain Auto Linking plugin for top level domain (.com,.cc,.co), see the answer below

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement cross-domain tracking between the two sites, which isn't trivial.  There's good advice here:

[Google Analytics Cross Domain Tracking and _setDomainName()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534793/google-analytics-cross-domain-tracking-and-setdomainname)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to s6mike you can also implement the Cross-Domain Auto Linking plugin:

To simplify the cross domain linking proces say you have a website hosted on source.com that you want to track with cross domain tracking:

- destination.com
- test.destination.com/page2
- test.dest3.com?page4

**Code**

```
//Load the plugin.
ga('require', 'linker');
```

Define domains

```
// Define which domains to autoLink.
ga('linker:autoLink', ['destination.com', 'dest3.com']);
```

or define with regular expression

```
// Define which domains to autoLink using a regular expression.
ga('linker:autoLink', [/^example\.(com|net)$/]);
```

set `allowLinker` configuration parameter to `true`

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'auto', {
  'allowLinker': true
});
```

**resource**

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#autolink

**EDIT**

Once you have domain linking established, you will see only the request URI in the content reports, and not the top-level or sub-domain for a given page.

1. Set up a master view (profile) for your primary domain without filters.
2. Create a view (profile) especially for cross-domain tracking and re-use master tracking code

   - View (Profile) Settings page -> Add Filter link
   - Add New Filter
   - Custom Filter -> Filter type settings: Advanced
   - FieldA to Hostname & FieldB to Request URI
   - Set the values for both Field A and Field B to (.*)
   - Set the Output To --> Constructor option to Request URI: $A1$B1

Your reports will now show:

```
example.com/index.php
example.net/more.php
example.cz/more.php
```

**resource**

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite?csw=1#keyComponents