# Google Analytics - multiple domains with multiple subdomains

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain

I'm trying to set up Google Analytics for my blog platform. The problem is that I have few top domains and users who can choose their blog address with their name ("john") and one of the top domains. The user's blog address is like john.domain3.com .

I was trying to set up everything like here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite , with top domain name in analytics code:

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domain3']);
```

but in reports every time when user change domain after clicking a link it creates new session. I use

```
 onclick="_gaq.push(['_link','https://www.A.com/']); return false;"
```

of course.

I tried also to set setDomainName to 'none' like some articles say. In reports it seems ok but it sets up new cookie for every subdomain and I have to link with gaq.push also subdomains of the same domain.

I've read that topic:
[Google Analytics Cross Domain Tracking and _setDomainName()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534793/google-analytics-cross-domain-tracking-and-setdomainname)
but it's not exactly the same (without subdomains).

Can anyone out there give me some hint? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have multiple top-level domains (domaina.com and domainb.com) and multiple subdomains (john.domaina.com and jane.domaina.com) you'll need to follow the setup instructions here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#multipleDomains

For your GA code on domaina.com and any subdomain of domaina.com (eg., john.domaina.com) you must use `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domaina.com']);`. You don't need to add the onclick code to links between those domains.

Then for the GA code on domainb.com you must use `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domainb.com']);`. You DO have to add the onlick code to links between this domain and domaina.com.

Also important to note that for your GA code on both sites you're also including `_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);` right after setDomainName.

Hope that helps.