# Google analytics for multiple domain aliases

Tags: .htaccess, google-analytics, cross-domain

How can I have Google Analytics recognize when one of my domain aliases is being used?  It seems that Analytics metrics are only being captured when the visitor uses the site's original domain: mysite.com.

I have 5 domain aliases that all point to example.com/index.html.  I do this redirect by the following htaccess code:

```
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?alias1\.info$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.html?north [R=301,QSA,L]
```

The site and the five domain aliases are all hosted in the same location. These are not sub domains.

Comment: Are you trying to get GA to track multiple domains? There's some [documentation for that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534793/google-analytics-cross-domain-tracking-and-setdomainname).

Comment: Yes, but my situation is unique and not mentioned in that documentation.  I am not trying to capture data on a different site's traffic; I am trying to capture traffic data when my site's domain aliases are used.

Comment: Do you have any filters in place on the view in GA that would limit it to a single domain?

Answer (score 1):

You should put your base URL in this part of the code: `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'alias-of-domain.com']);`. You should recognize the base URL for each alias and change this part of the code for each of the aliases. After that, you need to create a new view for each of the aliases in the Analytics and apply a filter to each one of them.

Check Google documentation, everything is explained here: [Tracking Multiple Domains - Web Tracking (ga.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#profilesKey).

If you are using Universal Analytics, then check [this page](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en-GB).