# google analytics multi domain aliases web

Tags: dns, google-analytics, aliases

i have multidomain web site, but i'm not sure, if i'm tracking it in good way.

Primary domain: www.domain.com
Domain aliases: www.domain.sk, www.domain.cz (each show content from .COM but in other languages)

I created in analytics new profile for multi domain web.

My tracking code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'ACCOUNT_ID']);
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domain.<? echo $url_localization; ?>']);
        _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
</script>
```

Is this right way? How can i filter visits in analytics by domains?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need track visitors across multiple domains (see [documentation for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534793/google-analytics-cross-domain-tracking-and-setdomainname)), I think the better solution would be creating more separate properties (within one GA account). You will need to change the UA-XXXXXX-X id number on each website, but you won't have to play around with filters and also, this would help avoid the volume limits (currently 10 million per property - not strictly applied by Google as of yet though).